# Text cleaning did not work properly in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, python-re

I downloaded the text analysis dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/datatattle/covid-19-nlp-text-classification).

The data looks like
[image]

OriginalTweet contains @,http,// and other signs.

I want to remove those and clean the text.

The code for cleaning the OriginalTweet

```
def remove_url(text): 
    url_pattern  = re.compile('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
    return url_pattern.sub(r'', text)

train_data['OriginalTweet'] = train_data['OriginalTweet'].apply(remove_url)
```

There were no compilation errors however my code was unable to clear the `OriginalTweet` column.

Thank you.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  What do you mean by "my code was unable to clear the OriginalTweet column"?  Please clarify by editing your original question to replace image with sample data and provide an example of what result you need.

Comment: The [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) looks like your input is UTF-8 but was imported as Windows code page 1252 or some such. The proper solution to that would be to specify `encoding="utf-8"` when opening the input file.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer would be

```
def clean_data(text):
    text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ',text)
    return text

train_data['OriginalTweet'] = train_data['OriginalTweet'].apply(clean_data)
```

Comment: This does not get rid of e.g. `http`.